# jquery menus not appearing in front of wrap with back color containing a div with background image

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

The problem that I am facing, is that the circular menus using jquery, after opening I can't see all of the choices in the scree, I've got two menus, the first appears on top of the wrap, and the other appear below the first menu.
What a I'm trying to do is, when I do mousehover to the first menu, I want to view all the choices, and the wrap element stretches to englobe all the choices, I need a scrollbar to appear so I can move up a see the choices.
Here is the code.
default.css

```
.socials {
display:block;
width:32px;
height:32px;
background:url(../img/socials/share.png) no-repeat;
cursor:pointer;
position:relative;
}

.nature {
display:block;
width:150px;
height:150px;
background:url(../img/nature/img1.png) no-repeat;
cursor:pointer;
position:relative;


}



.socials, .nature {
margin:0 auto;
}

.socials {
margin-bottom:50px;
}

ul.reset,
ul.reset li {
display:block;
list-style:none;
padding:0;
margin:0;

}

ul.reset li {
position:absolute;
}

ul.reset li a {
outline:none;
}

#content {
margin:100px auto 0;
width:560px;
}


a {
color:#fff;
}

a img {
border:none;
}
```

the style.css

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
border: 0 none;
font-family: inherit;
font-size: 100%;
font-style: inherit;
font-weight: inherit;
margin: 0;
outline: 0 none;
padding: 0;
vertical-align: baseline;
}
body {
background-color: #000000;

}
 #wrap {
background-color:#FECC80;
margin:25px auto;
width: 940px;
min-height:560px;


 }
.centered {
 margin:25px auto;
width: 940px;
min-height:560px;
background:url("../Images/logo.png") no-repeat center center;

 position:fixed;
 }

/*menu em cima*/
nav {width: 100%;
position:fixed;
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
top:0;

 }


    nav ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        display: table;

        width: 100%;
    }
    nav li {
        z-index:10;
        text-align: center;
        display: table-cell;
               width: 120px
    }
    nav a {
             opacity: 0.5;
   filter: alpha(opacity=50);
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 5px 10px ;
        height: 30px;
        line-height: 20px;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        background: #D98134;
        border-right:1px solid white;

    }

    nav  a:hover {
          opacity:1;
 filter: alpha(opacity=100);
background-color: #D98134;
}



 /*menu de baixo*/


 nav2 {width: 100%;
position:fixed;
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
bottom:0;

}


    nav2 ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        display: table;

        width: 100%;
    }
    nav2 li {
        z-index:10;
        text-align: center;
        display: table-cell;
               width: 120px
    }
    nav2 a {
             opacity: 0.5;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 5px 10px ;
        height: 30px;
        line-height: 20px;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        background: #D98134;
        border-right:1px solid white;

    }

    nav2  a:hover {
          opacity:1;
 filter: alpha(opacity=100);
background-color: #D98134;
}
```

And here goes the part  from  produtos.php
 where i have the problems

```
<div class="centered">
</div>

<div class="nature" >
        <ul class="reset" >
            <li><a href="#"><img src="../img/nature/img2.png" alt="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="../img/nature/img3.png" alt="" /></a></li>

        </ul>           
    </div>




    <div class="nature"  >
        <ul class="reset">
            <li><a href="#"><img src="../img/nature/img2.png" alt="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="../img/nature/img3.png" alt="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="../img/nature/img4.png" alt="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="../img/nature/img2.png" alt="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="../img/nature/img3.png" alt="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="../img/nature/img4.png" alt="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="../img/nature/img2.png" alt="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="../img/nature/img3.png" alt="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="../img/nature/img4.png" alt="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="../img/nature/img2.png" alt="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="../img/nature/img3.png" alt="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="../img/nature/img4.png" alt="" /></a></li>

        </ul>           
    </div>
</div>

</div>
```

You can view the site working in 
http://ocafe.pt/Teste/produtos.php and view in first hand the problem.

Comment: I think your problem is CSS related, and nothing to do with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I have been playing with some ideas:

for starters, your fixed attribute on the .centered div is mucking you around big time.

Here is a possible solution at: http://jsfiddle.net/webwarrior/LSn6F/34/

Changed some css, and added some elements:

```
<div id="wrap2"></div>

 <div id="wrap">

<div class="centered">
</div>

<div class="nature">
            <ul class="reset" style="display: block; z-index: 50; opacity: 0; ">
                <li style="top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 50; "><a href="#"><img src="http://ocafe.pt/img/nature/img2.png" alt=""></a></li>
                <li style="top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 49; "><a href="#"><img src="http://ocafe.pt/img/nature/img3.png" alt=""></a></li>

            </ul>            
        <a class="trigger" style="display: block; position: absolute; z-index: 1; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; "></a></div>




        <div class="nature">
            <ul class="reset" style="display: block; z-index: 50; opacity: 0; ">
                <li style="top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 49; "><a href="#"><img src="http://ocafe.pt/img/nature/img2.png" alt=""></a></li>
                <li style="top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 49; "><a href="#"><img src="http://ocafe.pt/img/nature/img3.png" alt=""></a></li>
                <li style="top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 49; "><a href="#"><img src="http://ocafe.pt/img/nature/img4.png" alt=""></a></li>
                <li style="top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 49; "><a href="#"><img src="http://ocafe.pt/img/nature/img2.png" alt=""></a></li>
                <li style="top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 49; "><a href="#"><img src="http://ocafe.pt/img/nature/img3.png" alt=""></a></li>
                <li style="top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 49; "><a href="#"><img src="http://ocafe.pt/img/nature/img4.png" alt=""></a></li>
                <li style="top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 49; "><a href="#"><img src="http://ocafe.pt/img/nature/img2.png" alt=""></a></li>
                <li style="top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 49; "><a href="#"><img src="http://ocafe.pt/img/nature/img3.png" alt=""></a></li>
                <li style="top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 49; "><a href="#"><img src="http://ocafe.pt/img/nature/img4.png" alt=""></a></li>
                <li style="top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 49; "><a href="#"><img src="http://ocafe.pt/img/nature/img2.png" alt=""></a></li>
                <li style="top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 50; "><a href="#"><img src="http://ocafe.pt/img/nature/img3.png" alt=""></a></li>
                <li style="top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 49; "><a href="#"><img src="http://ocafe.pt/img/nature/img4.png" alt=""></a></li>

            </ul>            
        <a class="trigger" style="display: block; position: absolute; z-index: 1; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; "></a></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrap2 {
    background-color:#FECC80;
    margin:25px auto;
    width: 940px;
    min-height:560px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -25%;
}
#wrap {
    background-color:#FECC80;
    margin:25px auto;
    width: 940px;
    min-height:560px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -25%;
    overflow: visible;
}
.centered {
    margin:25px auto;
    width: 940px;
    min-height:560px;
    background:url("http://ocafe.pt/Images/logo.png") no-repeat center center;
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    position: absolute;
    top: -25%;
    left: 0%;

}
```

hth

we will get there after a bit of fiddling...

Comment: It didnt work, i will try to start a new project, a see if im missing something....